# SQL Connection using XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to read SQL info from a XML file. I am getting this error on the SQL conn string :

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <xml encoding="UTF8">
 <configuration>
 <appsettings>
 <servername>127.0.0.1</servername>
  <username>sa</username>
  <password>RandomlyZE6</password>
  <database>TelecomNames</database>
 </appsettings>
</configuration>
</xml>
```

My code :

```
var doc = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/DBConn.xml");
var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

var serverName = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/servername");
//  var serverIP = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/serverport");
var username = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/username");
var password = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/password");
var database = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/database");

var connection = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets = True;", serverName, database, username, password));

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection.ToString())) ;
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("use TelecomNames SELECT xName FROM dbo.Character", connection);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

The error is on that line

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection.ToString()))
```

Thanks

Comment: Mind to share xml content?

Comment: You do create a `new SqlConnection` and afterwards use `toString()` on it to create a new one (see `SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection.ToString())`) - why?? this can't work!

Comment: Just remove line with using statement

Comment: **(a)** why aren't you just using the standard .NET config file format for a connection string? Why re-invent the wheel? And **(b)** if you **must** use your own approach, then I'd recommend you at least use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build the valid connection string from the individual pieces of information (instead of concatenating it yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var doc = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/DBConn.xml");

var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

var serverName = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/servername");
var username = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/username");
var password = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/password");
var database = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/database");

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + serverName + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";User Id=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets = True"))
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("use TelecomNames SELECT xName FROM dbo.Character", connection);
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
while (reader.Read())
{

}

connection.Close();

}
```